# Angular UI Bootstrap modal binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my AngularJS module:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('modalInstanceController', function ($scope, $modalInstance, message) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = message;
    })
    .controller('ParentController', function ($scope, $modal) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myFolder/modal.html',
            backdrop: 'static',
            windowClass: 'custom-modal-wait',
            dialogFade: false,
            keyboard: false,
            controller: 'modalInstanceController',
            resolve: {
                message: function () {
                    return "Doing something...";
                }
            }
        });
});
```

And my template:

```
<div ng-controller="modalInstanceController as modalInstanceCtrl" class="modal-body">
    <div>{{modalInstanceCtrl.message}}</div>
    <img src="..\..\Content\img.gif">
</div>
```

Why model binding is not working? Instead of message I see `{{modalInstanceCtrl.message}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `ng-app="mymodule"`. I hope this would help.